# JQUERY scrollTo won't let me scroll after executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto

Im using the following JQUERY to hide an element upon scroll and then scroll back to the top of the page to display the new element:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
 }
 else {
    $("#hero-area").slideUp(1300);
    $(".timeline").show(2000);
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
 return false;
 }
});
```

Problem is, it scrolls back to the top of the page just fine but after execution it refuses to let me continue scrolling the page. I have tried returning false, but no luck. Maybe because im using an IF statement?

Answer (score 1):

--Update--
One approach to your question, load once is to set a global variable and check it before you run it like so...

```
    var canRun = true; //declare a global variable
    $(function () { //on page load
        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
                if (canRun) {
                    //Do your animation
                    //set the global to false
                    canRun = !canRun;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

---

If `$(window).scrollTop() = 0` it would go to the `else` block and then try to scroll up again.Just looooooooping.

If you want to play with the `"#hero-area"` element after passing 200 then you want to get rid of your `else` block, take that code put it inside `if` and not worry about the rest.

Hope that helps. If that didn't answer your question let me know.

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation, I must seem rather silly as I still can't figure out how to make the script only execute once, and not continue :(


` $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {

   $("#hero-area").slideUp(1300);
    $(".timeline").show(2000);
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
    return false;
}`

});`